# unable to get the Specialcells property of the range class for xlcelltypevisible

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro that I run once a week. I have a piece of code that filters out for different data and then copies the remaining cells to a different worksheet

Here is the portion of effected code:

```
dim data as worksheet
dim sku vp as worksheet
Set skuvp = Workbooks("weekly Brand snapshot report.xlsx").Sheets("SKU VP")
set data = Workbooks("weekly Brand snapshot report.xlsx").Sheets("SKU Data")

data.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Foods", Operator:=xlFilterValues
data.Range("Onsales[[Product]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("B2")
skuvp.Range("foods").Sort key1:=skuvp.Range("C1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
data.ShowAllData

data.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Treats", Operator:=xlFilterValues
data.Range("Onsales[[Product]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("H2")
skuvp.Range("treats").Sort key1:=skuvp.Range("I1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
data.ShowAllData

data.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Hardgoods", Operator:=xlFilterValues
data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("N2")
skuvp.Range("hard").Sort key1:=skuvp.Range("O1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
data.ShowAllData

data.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Specialty", Operator:=xlFilterValues
data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("T2")
skuvp.Range("spcl").Sort key1:=skuvp.Range("U1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
data.ShowAllData
```

Data and skuvp are set as worksheets.

This code ran fine the very first time I ran it.  However, it began having an error after that. The error appears on this line:

```
data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("N2")
```

The error it gives is "Unable to get the Specialcells property of the range class."

I originally had the range in that code set the table column "Onsales[[Product]]" as the range like the previous 2 times I used the code but changed it to a set range to see if that would fix the issue.

Why is this code having an error on that line when the same basic code works a few lines earlier?

I've searched stackoverflow and other online sources for a solution without success.

Comment: data and skuvp are defined as Worksheets. They are set as follows: Set data = Workbooks("weekly Brand snapshot report.xlsx").Sheets("SKU Data") and Set skuvp = Workbooks("weekly Brand snapshot report.xlsx").Sheets("SKU VP")

Comment: Try replacing `xlCellTypeVisible` with its converted value `12` so that the line reads `data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(12).Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("N2")`  Do you get the same error if you do that?

Comment: @tigeravatar when I did your fix it had a different error. the error code says Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: hmm... hard to tell if that's from your `data` worksheet or your `skuvp` worksheet because they're both used in that line of code.  Try introducing a new line of code to see if it runs or not, it's just a check for the range address generated by the specialcells: `MsgBox data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(12).Address` and see if you get the new error or if it shows a messagebox with the *expected* address

Comment: Is there always visible data when `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is invoked?

Comment: @Demetri I thought about that but given 16353 rows...pretty sad not to have at least _one_ XD

Comment: @Demetri the code that is triggering the error has over 9000 rows still visible at that point

Comment: @tigeravatar the msgbox code ran fine and displayed the ranges that were still visible.

Comment: @pengdiddy, try: `data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(12).Cells.Copy` .

Comment: @fadi your code seems to have done the trick. I've ran it multiple times trying to trigger the error and it hasn't had an issue. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @pengdiddy, You are welcome, happy that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from comments it seems that the problem is solved by using `.Cells` :

```
data.Range("B2:B16354").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Copy Destination:=skuvp.Range("N2")
```